# I can't add component because "there is error" but I can't see it. How can I solve the problem?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I work on a game. A part is offline and the other one using network.
I've create a copy of my script to work offline. There is no error on my script (monobehaviour) but when I tried to add the component on my GameObject unity throw me an error :

> "Can't add script component 'RocketOffline' because the script class
>   cannot be found. Make sure that there are no compile errors and that
>   the file name and class name match"

I don't see any error in my script and names match (`RocketOffline.cs` VS `RocketOffline : MonoBehaviour`)

I've tried to re-import my script, re-import all assets and copy all of my code in another script but nothing seem to works...

I've same problem on other script but I'll only show one of them

```cs
public class RocketOffline : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Explosion;

    private Vector3 Direction;
    private Color Couleur;
    private float vitesse;
    private float multiplieur;
    int NumPlayer;


    void Explose(Vector3 position)
    {
        ExplosionOffline instance = Instantiate(Explosion, position, new Quaternion()).GetComponent<ExplosionOffline>();
        instance.NumPlayer = NumPlayer;
        foreach (var SmokeEffect in GetComponentsInChildren<ParticleSystem>())
        {
            SmokeEffect.transform.parent = null;
            Destroy(SmokeEffect.gameObject, SmokeEffect.startLifetime);
            SmokeEffect.Stop();
        }
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        Explose(transform.position);
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        GetComponent<Collider>().isTrigger = false;

    }

    public void SetSpeed(Vector3 _Direction, float _Vitesse, JoueurOffline _Player)
    {
        Direction = _Direction;
        vitesse = _Vitesse;
        Couleur = _Player.Couleur;
        NumPlayer = _Player.NumPlayer;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        Rigidbody rigid = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.forward * Mathf.Atan2(-Direction.x, Direction.y) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        rigid.velocity = Direction * vitesse;
        multiplieur = transform.localScale.y / 10;
        GetComponentInChildren<MeshRenderer>().material.color = Couleur;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = transform.up * vitesse;
        RaycastHit info;
        Physics.Raycast(new Ray(transform.position, GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity * Time.deltaTime), out info);
        if (info.distance < vitesse * Time.deltaTime * multiplieur/* && info.collider.gameObject != gameObject && info.collider.gameObject != player.gameObject*/)
        {
            Explose(info.point);
        }
    }
}
```

I only want to add my script on my `GameObject` like usually on Unity.
But there is always the same error.
My script was tested on other project and work perfectly. I think it's probably an internal bug of unity.

Comment: What is different from the other project where you say it works and this one?

Comment: Sadly, nothing.
But when I've create this script the original name was Rocket_Offline. But we can't use underscore in class name, so I've change it to RocketOffline. Since that there is error. But the two script are the same...

Answer (score 0):

Yep, this is potentially a bug of Unity.
If you're using the new 2019 beta, then just do a Bug Report :)

Comment: I'm using unity 2018 ^^
But yes, I'll send a bug report.

So do you think there is no solution and I should create another project ?

Thanks

Comment: Yep, try copying the code in another class with another name

Answer (score 0):

i think you can try to reimport the script or rm the library folder of your project.

Comment: Thanks, but I've already tryed :(
I was obliged to create another project. And finally I've copy paste my script and now all works perfectly
But thanks all for you repply